# How to set default layer visible in openlayers 2

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers

I have two layers and switcher in openlayers. After init immediately I would like to set second layer to be visible, but still showed first added layer.
I tried: setVisibility, setBaseLayer, but without successful. 
Here is part of code:

```
var gmapLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google sattelite", { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, visibility: false });
var gmapStreetLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google streets", { visibility: false });
map.addLayer(gmapLayer);
map.addLayer(gmapStreetLayer);
```

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

After init I tried:

```
map.setBaseLayer(selLayer);
//or
selLayer.setVisibility(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found problem. I used setBaseLayer wrong because called to array see:

```
var selLayer = map.getLayersByName(selectedLayer);
if (selLayer !== null) {        
    map.setBaseLayer(selLayer);        //<---Wrong
}
```

Right solutions is:

```
var selLayer = map.getLayersByName(selectedLayer);
if (selLayer !== null) {        
    map.setBaseLayer(selLayer[0]);        //<--Good
}
```